# How to Check/enable parity in Boost serial Port?

Tags: c++, boost

```
//start function
bool SerialPort::start(const char *com_port_name, int baud_rate)
        {
            boost::system::error_code ec;
            if (port_) {
                std::cout << "error : port is already opened..." << std::endl;
                return false;
            }

            port_ = serial_port_ptr(new boost::asio::serial_port(io_service_));
            port_->open(com_port_name, ec);
            if (ec) {
                std::cout << "error : port_->open() failed...com_port_name="
                    << com_port_name << ", e=" << ec.message().c_str() << std::endl; 
                return false;
            }

            // option settings...
            port_->set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(baud_rate));
            port_->set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::character_size(8));
            port_->set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits::one));
            port_->set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity::even));
            port_->set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control::none));

            boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service_));

            async_read_some_();

            return true;
        }

        void SerialPort::async_read_some_()
        {
            if (port_.get() == NULL || !port_->is_open()) return;

            port_->async_read_some( 
                boost::asio::buffer(read_buf_raw_, SERIAL_PORT_READ_BUF_SIZE),
                boost::bind(
                    &SerialPort::on_receive_,
                    this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, 
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }

        void SerialPort::on_receive_(const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t bytes_transferred)
        {

            if (ec) {
                cout << "error" << endl;
                return;
             }
        }
```

I have set option to even parity in my embedded device and try to perform communication by selecting odd parity in my PC.

As per the rule, Communication should not succeed and generate parity mismatch error. However I can communicate successfully at both end.

How to detect parity mismatch in boost serial port programming ?

Comment: How do you observe this? The code shown will not do any communication anyways. Also, you have a runaway thread that is never joined. Can you show a SSCCE?  Here's my starter for you: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/461d4cdd0108e1c5

Comment: It is just a example;Complete code works in embedded device and it is fine but did not generate any error in case of different parity between Rx and Tx

Comment: Just to be clear: if you don't post actual code the problem will probably not be visible or be masked by the more superficial problems.  Your call